# Different dimensions depending on screen size, one in dp and another to match parent

Tags: android

This probably has an easy solution but I haven't been able to find it after searching online.

I have a view which I want to be of a different height depending on screen size (orientation in most cases). I have achieved this in the past by having a dimens resource file for different screen sizes. This is straight forward if both values are in dps. My problem is that in one of the cases I want to set a dp value and in the other case I want it to match_parent.

I don't want to re-creating an extra layout just for this, so I was hoping there was a solution like if both values were in dp.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a solution!

According to [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html#MATCH_PARENT):

> `MATCH_PARENT` has an integer value, which is `-1`.

So in the first `dimen.xml` file, you can have `48dp` (or whatever) and in the second dimen.xml (for other screen sizes for example), you can have `-1px` (not `dp`) and you'll get what you hope for!

Comment: Didn't work for me on 5.0
I used it for width. My text view is following wrap_content when using -1px in dimens